# Allow decimal separator comma or period according to country

Tags: jquery, localization

I have e-commerce website working for different countries have one expected price i want to allow comma or dot as decimal separator according to country because different countries are having different decimal separators.

I can get my locale in JS file want to do this in JQuery.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you search for that??? If ya, where are you stuck? `I can get my locale in JS file want to do this in JQuery`I'm not sure to understand

Comment: yaa I searched for that i got some plugins to format currency but not able to find anything like where we can pass the locale value and get the separator value whether it is Comma(,) or Dot(.).

Comment: I have my locale code or say ISO code

Comment: You could just replace comma with dot before validating string or use a regex handling both to validate. This is too broad question without seeing exactly what you are doing

Comment: What does "allow" mean? Do you want to *display* numbers? Read them from input fields? Where do numbers come from and why aren't they already formatted?

Comment: Currently user can enter comma and dot both for US currency after dot it will allow only 4 places but for Norway  dot works like thousand separator and comma works as decimal separator so i want to get decimal separator according to country code.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario allow means its a text field where user can fill expected price of item

Comment: yup now i have implemented autonumeric plugin